.net library to deserialize Microsoft Marketplace webhook request body
I'm creating a SaaS webhook endpoint to called by Microsoft.
This is the official documentation I'm following :
Implementing a webhook on the SaaS service
I'm looking for a proper .net library that can deserialize the request body. Because in the documentation says
"ISVs should avoid strict deserialization of the Webhook schema. Microsoft reserves the right to expand the schema in future."
I've tried using Marketplace.SaaS.Client library but it doesn't have any support for webhook request body deserialize
Marketplace.SaaS.Client
For Now I'm using simple Json deserializer
string body = await new StreamReader(Request?.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
var bodyObject = (JObject)JsonCovert.DeserializeObject(body);
string tenantId = bodyObject.SelectToken("subscription.beneficiary.tenantId").ToString();

Webhook payload example as follows
{
    "id": "<guid>",
    "activityId": "<guid>",
    "publisherId": "XXX",
    "offerId": "YYY",
    "planId": "plan2",
    "quantity": 10,
    "subscriptionId": "<guid>",
    "timeStamp": "2023-02-10T18:48:58.4449937Z",
    "action": "ChangePlan",
    "status": "InProgress",
    "operationRequestSource": "Azure",
    "subscription":
    {
      "id": "<guid>",
      "name": "Test",
      "publisherId": "XXX",
      "offerId": "YYY",
      "planId": "plan1",
      "quantity": 10,
      "beneficiary":
        {
          "emailId": XX@outlook.com,
          "objectId": "<guid>",
          "tenantId": "<guid>",
          "puid": "1234567890",
        },
      "purchaser":
        {
          "emailId": XX@outlook.com,
          "objectId": "<guid>",
          "tenantId": "<guid>",
          "puid": "1234567890",
        },
      "allowedCustomerOperations": ["Delete", "Update", "Read"],
      "sessionMode": "None",
      "isFreeTrial": false,
      "isTest": false,
      "sandboxType": "None",
      "saasSubscriptionStatus": "Subscribed",
      "term":
        {
          "startDate": "2022-02-10T00:00:00Z",
          "endDate": "2022-03-12T00:00:00Z",
          "termUnit": "P1M",
          "chargeDuration": null,
        },
      "autoRenew": true,
      "created": "2022-01-10T23:15:03.365988Z",
      "lastModified": "2022-02-14T20:26:04.5632549Z",
    },
    "purchaseToken": null
}

